# Breaks on production mode in vue

Tags: vue.js

I've imported lodash as (import _ from 'lodash') note: I've not installed lodash package but it worked fine until yesterday. But today it breaks like this, in chunkvendor.js file:

[image: Dev tools syntax error]

Comment: what are the errors you got when you run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that lodash of some unknown version is used by some other package. Install it explicitly because you use it directly.

Comment: I added it explicitly but still the issue occurs.